# HTML5 pattern for IP address - how to modify pattern to ignore the "_" (underscore) character

Tags: regex, html, ip-address

I have found the following pattern for validating the syntax of an IP address:

```
 pattern="((^|\.)((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d\d)|([1-9]?\d))){4}$"
```

But I need to modify that to ignore `_` characters in all places. That is because I use an input mask (it removes the `_` after defocusing the field but the bootstrap validator plugin sometime doesn't catch it).

So how I can modify that regex to ignore `_` characters?

Example strings which should be valid:

```
 192.168.88.1__  
 192.168.88_.200
 192.16_.88_.2__
 192.168.88.2
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example valid and invalid strings? I see it matches IP addresses, but I also see it can match everything in the beginning, too. See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJ8kG0/2). Please feel free to modify it to show what you need. Also, keep in mind that `pattern` regex is anchored by default.

Comment: Sure, for example:    192.168.88.1__ or 192.168.88_.200

Comment: Your regex [does not match those strings](https://regex101.com/r/kJ8kG0/3). Do you want to match them?

Comment: Yes, I want that the regex accept this strings too, but normal like 192.168.88.1 it schould accept too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match optional characters (0 or more occurrences), you need a `*` quantifier. So, to match the IP addresses with `_` after the numbers, you can add `_*` after each number:

```
((^|\.)((25[0-5]_*)|(2[0-4]\d_*)|(1\d\d_*)|([1-9]?\d_*))){4}_*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJ8kG0/5)

Although, I think that you can remove anchors safely since HTML5 *pattern* attribute is anchored by default. You can also change the regex to match the IP more intelligently (without allowing a dot before it):

```
(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)_*(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)_*){3}
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJ8kG0/7)